# Check if Column C contains values from both Column A and Column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with three columns. First Name (column A), Last Name (column B), Full Name (column C), and another Full Name (column D). The full names in column C and column D are from two different sources.
I want to compare column C and column D and search for duplicates. Now the issue here is that column D user has got middle names with it because the data is coming from a different source. The same user don't have middle names in column C.
So when I do the normal comparison and check for duplicates using the conditional formatting, it does not show me the duplicate because the name contains middle name of the user.

Is there any formula that can check if the Column D contains values from ? I tried to use the conditional formatting but it gives me incorrect data because of the middle name of the user.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSpQC.png)

Comment: Can you show us sample data please? That will help contributors understand the problem better and post solutions.

Comment: You need to show sample data with expected results. For instance; First == A, Last == B. Would you consider the name 'A B C' valid duplicate? Where the last name is used as a middle name? What about 'A Bc' where B is part of a larger last name... so many angels to think about on this one.

Comment: I modified the question and added sample data as well

Answer (score 0):

What about this formula? It checks for a piece of text within another one and in case of not found, and error is generated. The multiplication does the rest:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2;C2)*FIND(B2;C2));FALSE;TRUE)
```

(Edit after [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben)'s comment)

A shorter version of this formula is:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A2;C2)*FIND(B2;C2)))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @BigBen: indeed: translating the result of an `IsError()` into `True` and `False`, just as an input for conditional formatting, there are shorter ways to handle this. I've edited my answer accordingly.